# MongoDB - query collection to return all docs with latest version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am fairly new to Mongo, and I have the following task:

Running Mongo 3.4.2.

Collection:

```
[
  {
    "docID": "aaa111",
    "version": 1,
    "somefield1": "abc"
  },
  {
    "docID": "aaa111",
    "version": 2,
    "somefield1": "abc",
    "somefield2": "abc"
  },
  {
    "docID": "bbb222",
    "version": 1,
    "somefield1": "abc",
    "somefield2": "abc"
  },
  {
    "docID": "bbb222",
    "version": 2,
    "somefield1": "abc",
    "somefield3": "abc"
  },
  {
    "docID": "bbb222",
    "version": 3,
    "somefield2": "abc",
    "somefield3": "abc"
  }
]
```

In other words, documents with the same docID could have different "schema".

What I need the query of this collection to return are documents having the latest version, with all the fields of those specific documents.

Here is what the query output based on the above collection should look like:

```
[
  {
    "docID": "aaa111",
    "version": 2,
    "somefield1": "abc",
    "somefield2": "abc"
  },
  {
    "docID": "bbb222",
    "version": 3,
    "somefield2": "abc",
    "somefield3": "abc"
  }
]
```

I have been trying to use the $aggregate operator as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    { $sort: { docID: 1, version: 1 } },
    { $group:
        {
            _id: "$docID",
            latestVersion: { $last: "$version" }
        }
    }
 ]
)
```

but this just returns 2 fields, docID and the latest version.

I then tried using the $in operator to select from that collection using find(), where $in would accept the above query, however, one issue is that $in expects and array, and secondly, I need to select the documents where docID and version match to the results of the subquery.

How do I get all the fields of the documents having the docID and the latest version?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$$ROOT` with the `$last` accumulator to get all the root document fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "docID": 1, "version": 1 }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$docID",
    "last": { "$last": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$last" }}
])
```

Comment: As a follow up question, are there alternatives if the data volume fed to the $group stage in the pipeline exceeds 100MB, which triggers the memory exceeded error?  The AllowDiskUse option is too slow to use.